# Properties of preimages and intersections of sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am working through Bert Mendelson's "Introduction to Topology" and am having some trouble with proofs.

The text in well presented but to get a proper understanding I am working through the excercises. I am still on Chapter 1 which deals with sets and for the most part the excercises seem trivial to the point where its seems to me no proof is needed BUT there are a couple of questions that have me stumped (there are no worked solutions a problem with most maths books I find).

I would really apreciate it if somebody could walk me through a few proofs (it will probably take more than a couple before I get my head into gear), so here a couple of the excercises..

First one that seems trivial to me but one I am having trouble forming a proof for,

Let $f: A\to B$ be given and let $\{Y_\beta\}_{\beta\in I}$ be an indexed family of subsets of $B$.

Prove: If $X\subset  A$, and $Y \subset  B$, then $$f\left(X\cap f^{-1}(Y)\right)=f(X)\cap Y.$$

Let $A$ be a set and $E\subset A$. The function $\chi_E: A\to\{0,1\}$ defined by $\chi_E(x)= 1$ if $x\in E$ and $\chi_E(x)=0$ if $x\notin E$ is called the characteristic function of $E$. Let $E$ and $F$ be subsets of $A$, show:
a) $\chi_{E\cap F} = \chi_E\cdot \chi_F$, where $\chi_E\cdot \chi_F(x)= \chi_E(x) \chi_F(x)$;

b) $\chi_{E\cup F} = \chi_E + \chi_F - \chi_{E\cap F}$, and find a similar expression for $\chi_{E\cup F\cup G}$.

Any help with this most appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean "Let $f: A \rightarrow B$" instead of, "Let $f: Y \rightarrow B$"?

Comment: what do you mean by $X_E\cap F$ or $X_E\cup F\cup G$ ? $X_E$ is a function whereas $F,G$ are sets.

Comment: I've edited to  clean that up so that it now makes sense.

Comment: Either you copied something wrong, or perhaps you should pick a different book. The indexed set of $Y_\beta$ seems to have nothing to do with the subsequent questions. The domain of $f$ seems to be wrong. And the second exercise itself seems as if it's not very useful.

Comment: @Moron You could make it better (having 2K rep)... as I did now, though I'm not going to invent a title that fits both parts of the question: with $f$ and with $\chi$. They should have been asked separately to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that in the first question, the $f:Y \to B$ should be $f: A \to B$.

Here's a general method for showing two sets $P$ and $Q$ are equal.

Step 1: show every element of $P$ is in $Q$.

Step 2: Show every element of $Q$ is in $P$.

Applying this to the first question, let

$$
b \in f(X\cap f^{-1}(Y)).
$$
I'll show that $b \in f(X) \cap Y$.

Because $b \in f(X\cap f^{-1}(Y))$, there must be some element $a \in X\cap f^{-1}(Y)$ with $f(a) = b$.

Since 
$$
a \in X\cap f^{-1}(Y)
$$
we know that $a \in X$ and $a \in f^{-1}(Y)$, so $f(a) \in Y$.

Now since $f(a) = b$, and $a \in X$, the element $b$ is in the image of $X$ under $f$, i.e., in $f(X)$.

And since $b = f(a) \in Y$ (see second-to-last sentence), we know that $b \in Y$. Since $b \in f(X)$ and $b \in Y$, we have $b \in f(X) \cap Y$, and we're done with part 1.

Now I suggest that you mimic this and try to do part 2.

Comment: In the second part : 

let v ∈ ƒ(X)∩Y.

I want to show that v ∈ ƒ(X∩ƒ⁻¹(Y)).

Because v ∈ ƒ(X)∩Y, there must be an element z ∈ ƒ(ƒ(X)∩Y).
I am lost at this part, I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: 1. You should *really* learn to use LaTeX for formatting stuff, to make it easier for those of us providing answer to do so. 2. From "$v \in f(X) \cap Y$", you can conclude two things: (a) $v \in f(X)$ and (b) $v \in Y$. From "a", you can conclude that there's an element $u \in X$ with $f(u) = v$. You have to work from there. What you wrote was correct (in the sense that choosing $z = f(v)$ shows that there's an element of that set), but it doesn't really go anywhere.

Comment: @ John I am getting LaTeX, hopefully I will be a pro at it by next week. Please check my solution for part  2.  Let z ∈ ƒ(x)∩Y be given. I want to show that z ∈ ƒ(X∩f⁻¹(Y)).
z ∈ ƒ(X)∩Y implies that z∈ƒ(X) and z∈Y.
Because z∈ ƒ(X), there exist v ∈ Y such that  z=ƒ(v).
Since z = ƒ(v) and z∈Y then v∈ ƒ⁻¹(Y).
Also since v ∈Y and v∈ ƒ⁻¹(Y) then v ∈ X∩ƒ⁻¹(Y).
Because  v ∈ X∩ƒ⁻¹(Y) and z = ƒ(v) then  z ∈ ƒ(X∩f⁻¹(Y)).

Comment: At a quick glance, and with me pretty tired, that looks correct. I can't promise it's right, but I'd give it a 95% chance. :)  You're on your way!

Comment: Actually, a small glitch: "Because $z \in f(X)$ there exists $v \in Y$ ..." should be "Because $z \in f(X)$ there exists $v \in X$ ..." And "Also, since $v \in Y$ and ..." should be "Also, since $v \in X$ and ..." With those two fixes, it's fine.